# Give me a code example usage for tensorflow's tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k

Tags: tensorflow

Can you give me a code example that uses `tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k`? I cannot find anything on the Internet... :(

If I have a multi-labeled dataset like this one (each example may have more than one target label):

(total number of classes = 5) 
y1 = [class_0, class_1] 
y2 = [class_1, class_2] 
y3 = [class_0]

and my system predicts:

prediction for y1 -> [0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0] 
prediction for y2 -> [0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.4] 
prediction for y3 -> [0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5]

How can I compute for k=3, for example?

P.S.: Feel free to suggest your own example, if you can't comprehend this one.

---

**EDIT**: My code so far:
I really don't get it... Pls advise for a single prediction (y1 only) as well as for several predictions at once (with different number of true classes in each).

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.local_variables_initializer().run()
y1 = tf.constant( np.array([0, 1])  )
y2 = tf.constant( np.array([1, 2])  )
y3 = tf.constant( np.array([0]) )
p1 = tf.constant( np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0]) )
p2 = tf.constant( np.array([0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.4]) )
p3 = tf.constant( np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5]) )
metric, update = tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k(tf.cast(y1, tf.int64), p1, 3)
print(sess.run(update))
```

Comment: With regards to your edit, `tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k` creates variables. When you run `tf.local_variables_initializer` at the beginning of the session, there aren't any local variables made yet. You need to run it before the `sess.run(update)` line, since Tensorflow cannot do time travel (yet). :)

Answer (score 1):

The `tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k` will be replaced by `tf.metrics.average_precision_at_k`. And by browsing the code in [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py), you will find that when your inputs are `y_true` and `y_pred`, this function will actually transform the `y_pred` to `y_pred_idx`, by using `top_k` function.

`y_true` is a tensor of shape (batch_size, num_labels), and `y_pred` is of shape (batch_size, num_classes)

You can also see some discussion in this [issue](https://github.com/broadinstitute/keras-rcnn/issues/6), and this example comes from this issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([[2], [1], [0], [3], [0]]).astype(np.int64)
y_true = tf.identity(y_true)

y_pred = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1],
                   [0.8, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05],
                   [0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2],
                   [0.6, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05],
                   [0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1]
                   ]).astype(np.float32)
y_pred = tf.identity(y_pred)

_, m_ap = tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k(y_true, y_pred, 3)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

stream_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables()]

tf_map = sess.run(m_ap)
print(tf_map)

print((sess.run(stream_vars)))

tmp_rank = tf.nn.top_k(y_pred,3)

print(sess.run(tmp_rank))
```

This line `stream_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables()]` helps you see the `two local_variables` which is created in this `tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k` function.

This line `tmp_rank = tf.nn.top_k(y_pred,3)` in order to helps you understand by changing the value of `k` ,the prediction index which is used in `tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k` .

You can change the value of `k` to see the different result, and the `tmp_rank` represents the index which is used in calculating  the average precision.

For example:
when `k=1`, only the first batch match the label, so the `average precision at 1` result will be `1/6 = 0.16666666`.
When `k=2`, the third batch will also match the label, so the `average precision at 2` result will be `(1+(1/2))/6=0.25`.

Answer (score 0):

```
metric, update = tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k(tf.stack(y1, y2, y3), tf.stack(p1, p2, p3), 3)
print session.run(update)
```

Comment: I always get something like:
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value average_precision_at_4_5/total
         [[Node: average_precision_at_4_5/total/read = Identity[T=DT_DOUBLE, _class=["loc:@average_precision_at_4_5/total"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](average_precision_at_4_5/total)]]

Comment: You need to initialize variables before using them in tensorflow, and the metrics use local variables internally. Run `tf.local_variables_initializer().run()` before any session.run and this should work.

Comment: I really don't get it... Pls advise for a single prediction (y1 only) as well as for several rpedictions at once (with different number of true classes in each) - my code in original question edit.